# Getting helper messages while generating extjs6 application by using sencha command

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I installed Snecha and downloaded Extjs6 then

```
sencha -sdk home/apps/ext-6.0.1 generate app loginapp6 /home/Senchaapplications/loginapp6
```

then the output is:

```
Sencha Cmd v6.2.0.103
Sencha Cmd provides several categories of commands and some global switches. In
most cases, the first step is to generate an application based on a Sencha SDK
such as Ext JS or Sencha Touch:

    sencha -sdk /path/to/sdk generate app MyApp /path/to/myapp

Sencha Cmd supports Ext JS 4.1.1a and higher and Sencha Touch 2.1 and higher.

To get help on commands use the help command:

    sencha help generate app

For more information on using Sencha Cmd, consult the guides found here:

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/


Options
  * --beta, -be - Enable beta package repositories
  * --cwd, -cw - Sets the directory from which commands should execute
  * --debug, -d - Sets log level to higher verbosity

  * --sdk-path, -sd - The location of the SDK to use for non-app commands
  * --strict, -st - Treats warnings as errors, exiting with error if any warnings are present
  * --time, -ti - Display the execution time after executing all commands

Categories
  * app - Perform various application build processes
  * compass - Wraps execution of compass for sass compilation
  * compile - Compile sources to produce concatenated output and metadata
  * cordova - Quick init Support for Cordova
     * phonegap - Quick init support for PhoneGap
  * repository - Manage local repository and remote repository connections
  * template - Commands for working with templates
  * theme - Commands for low-level operations on themes
  * web - Manages a simple HTTP file server
  * workspace - Commands to perform actions on the current workspace

Commands
  * upgrade - Upgrades Sencha Cmd
  * which - Displays the path to the current version of Sencha Cmd
```

it's supposed to generate loginapp6 folder with classic and modern, but it's not.

what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it's raised because of system user named changed.
I changed my system name KIGNs's to Learner. after this change If installed and try to generate the Extjs6 app using sencha , it's not generating.

I removed sencha cmd and Then  I created a new user as admin , then  after login as a new user and again installed sencha, now its ExtJS app is generating.

Answer (score -1):

Currently you are using higher version of sencha command.

sencha cmd : v6.2.0.103
ExtJs SDK : ext-6.0.1

Download lower version of sencha CMD from here :

https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/cmd-download/